# Список всех товаров более 1000

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить список всех товаров более 1000. Если точнее, необходимо получить массив наименований всех товаров в МоемСкладе. До 1000 товаров выдает без проблем, а как выдать весь список не понимаю.
Спасибо!

Дополню вопрос своим неработающим кодом Google Script:

```
    var URL = "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/product";
    var options = {
        "method":"get",
        "offset":"0",
        "limit":"1000",
        headers : {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + token
        }
      };
      var tovari = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL,options);
```

offset я делаю потом 1000, но список товаров выдает тот же, как и с оффсет равным 0. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

А теперь Внимание, правильный ответ, если вдруг кому понадобится:

```
var URL = "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/"
var URL1 = URL + "?limit=1000&offset=0";
var URL2 = URL + "?limit=1000&offset=1000";
var options = {
   "method":"get",
   headers : {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token
   }
};
var tovari_0_1000 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL1,options);
var tovari_1000_2000 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL2,options);
```

Comment: Делать сдвиг на 1000*шаг?

Comment: пояснил Ваш ответ в своем основном вопросе. Если кратко, то я не понимаю как делать этот сдвиг.

Comment: все, разобрался) тяжко вспоминается, однако, а ведь когда-то учил!

Comment: Ну видите, главное подсказать)

Comment: да в описании к апи четко написано 2 параметра, сколько выдавать и с каким смещением, это понятно было, только куда их сувать надо было вот в чем был вопрос) в любом случае, спасибо :)